# Azure AD B2C "email" claim is missing from JWT with standard sign up policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on a web app that uses AAD B2C for authentication, I have setup default inbuilt sign up/sign in flows for it, and its all working fine. However I have noticed that instead of returning a claim with a single primary email of the user, it instead returns a collection of emails, in my test case it is a collection which only contains my only email.
I'm curious, is it possible to configure it in such a way that it would include a primary email address claim to JWT when I sign in? From what I have seen when configuring attributes to collect/return for my base user flows, it is possible to collect email when the user signs in, but only "EmailAddresses" collection can be marked to be returned with the token. Is there a way to change this behavior, or is it by design and I am missing a bigger picture?

Comment: Thanks @Danich. Any reason to use standard sign up policy? Could you please use recommended sign up policy and let us know if issue still persists.

Comment: @Jit_MSFT Sorry, by "standard" I meant default. I do in fact use recommended sign up policy.

Comment: Here is the by design claims defined in Azure B2C sign up policy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design!

Take SignIn/SignUp Policy as an example, you can see that the **user attribute** displays the email address as a **string**.

[image]

But the **application claims** shows the email address as **StringCollection**.

[image]

The **user attributes** is the information which AAD B2C collects from user. So B2C collects only a single email, the `email address` is a string. But **jwt claims** is the information which B2C returns to the relying party app. since there can be more than one email here(coming from multiple resources, such as federated Idp), this is a collection. Therefore, it is normal for you to return a collection of `email address`. This is by design, and there is currently no way to change this behavior.

Comment: Why is breaking the OpenID Connect standard "by design"? This is extremely frustrating and it means you can't use Azure AD B2C with an OpenID Connect product due to it.

For anyone landing here, here is the bug report: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16566#issuecomment-647038528, and the helpful instructions from Gitlab to configure this properly: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/oidc.html#microsoft-azure-active-directory-b2c