# No email for id token for B2C built in flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid

I have B2C tenant for Azure Active Directory 1 (AD_1). I'd like to authenticate users from external AD_2. SignUp_SignIn flow was create for B2C tenant, all claims were selected. This flow related to custom open id provider with next settings, see below:

[image]

Within AD_2 I have app registration, see below

[image]

When I decode obtained token, I see no email value. I tried different variants for custom idp for email field, like `email`, `sub`  - nothing works. Have I missed something? My ui settings are next

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I registered one application in Azure AD tenant and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

In Token configuration, I added same **optional claims** for ID token like this:

[image]

Now, I configured Azure AD as an identity provider in B2C tenant by adding **custom IDP** with below parameters:

[image]

While running **Sign Up and Sign In** user flow, make sure to include **email addresses** claim like this:

[image]

When I ran the user flow, I got below login screen with **Custom IDP AAD** button:

[image]

After clicking **Custom IDP AAD** button, I got below screen to pick account where I selected **`Sri`** account:

[image]

In my case, I got below screen after completing authentication process with **claims from Azure AD**:

[image]

When I selected **Continue**, I got ***id_token*** with **`emails`** claim successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to select **Email addresses** in `Application claims` of user flow to get email in ***id_token***:

[image]

You need to add **`email`** as value while configuring **Custom IDP** for email field.

**References:**

[Set up sign-in for an Azure AD organization - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider)

[Azure AD B2C "email" claim is missing from JWT - Stack Overflow by **Carl Zhao**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66021121/azure-ad-b2c-email-claim-is-missing-from-jwt-with-standard-sign-up-policy)